# Python elif not working in order I want

Tags: python

`Transaction_Code` == `"W"`, `"w"`, `"D"` or `"d"`

if not, it should be running `Process_Invalid_Code(Previous_Balance)`

What is happening, however is if input for `Transaction_Code` != `"W"`, `"w"`, `"D"` or `"d"`, it then continues to run the `"What is your previous balance?"` and `"How much is the transaction amount?"` input...

ONLY THEN, after you give input for those does it run `Invalid_Transaction_Code`

What I WANT to happen is for it to throw `Invalid_Transaction_Code ("Invalid Transaction Code!")` etc. BEFORE without wasting the users time asking for Previous Balance and Transaction..

Does that make sense?

Here is the code

```
#The main function definition

def main():
    Name = input("What is your name?  ")
    Account_ID = input("What is your account ID?  ")
    Transaction_Code = input("Press W or w for Withdrawal, Press D or d for Deposit:  ")
    Previous_Balance = float(input("What is your previous balance?  "))
    Transaction_Amount = float(input("How much is the transaction amount?  "))

    if Transaction_Code == "W" or Transaction_Code == "w":
        Withdrawal_Process(Previous_Balance, Transaction_Amount)
    elif Transaction_Code == "D" or Transaction_Code == "d":
        Deposit_Process(Previous_Balance, Transaction_Amount)
    else:
        Process_Invalid_Code(Previous_Balance)

#Defines the Deposit Process

def Deposit_Process(Previous_Balance, Transaction_Amount):
    New_Balance = Transaction_Amount + Previous_Balance
    Print_Function(New_Balance)


#Defines the Withdrawal Process

def Withdrawal_Process(Previous_Balance, Transaction_Amount):
    if Transaction_Amount > Previous_Balance:
        print("Invalid Transaction: Not Sufficient Funds!")
        New_Balance = Previous_Balance
        Print_Function(New_Balance) 
    else:
        New_Balance = Previous_Balance - Transaction_Amount
        Print_Function(New_Balance)

#The Invalid Code Function Definition

def Process_Invalid_Code(Previous_Balance):
    New_Balance = Previous_Balance
    print ("Invalid Transaction Code!")
    print ("Please type W or w for Withdrawal")
    print ("or type D or d for Deposit")
    Print_Function(New_Balance)


#Defines the Print Function

def Print_Function(New_Balance):
    print ("Your balance is now $", format(New_Balance, '.2f'))  


#Call the main function

main()
```

Comment: What are you asking?? What is the issue you are having with your code?

Comment: You need to put an appropriate `if` statement in main() right after the Transaction_Code input line

Comment: Also, make your life easier, and cast your inputs to a single casing (use lower or upper) to change your input to upper case or lower case and compare to a single casing so then all you have to do is `Transaction_Code.lower() == "w"`. Or just do `Transaction_code in ('w', 'W')`

Comment: `Capital_Variable_Names` should only be placed on classes, not variables and methods

Comment: the `if`/`elif` is outside the main... is that on purpose or you just messed the indentation pasting the code?

Comment: You say "if not, it should be running Process_Invalid_Code(Previous_Balance)" and also "What I WANT to happen is for it to throw Invalid_Transaction_Code BEFORE without wasting the users time asking for Previous Balance " ... how do you propose it knows the Previous Balance without asking?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since all of your desired actions need `Previous_Balance` you must ask for it in any case:

```
def main():
    # never used, lets ask anyway
    Name = input("What is your name?  ")

    # we need this information at a minimum
    Previous_Balance = float(input("What is your previous balance?  "))
    Transaction_Code = input("Press W or w for Withdrawal, Press D or d for Deposit:  ")

    # if its a withdrawal/deposit, find the amount and account
    if Transaction_Code.upper() in "WD":
        # we never use this Account_ID ...
        Account_ID = input("What is your account ID?  ")
        Transaction_Amount = float(input("How much is the transaction amount?  "))
        if Transaction_Code.upper() == "W":
            Withdrawal_Process(Previous_Balance, Transaction_Amount)
        else:
            Deposit_Process(Previous_Balance, Transaction_Amount)
    else:
        # they've entered a bad code
        Process_Invalid_Code(Previous_Balance)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for.

Comment: This is for an assignment for an intro to programming course... I based my code off the pseudo code provided. Thus why I'm sure a lot of it is unnecessary/the slower way to do things

Answer (score 1):

You may want to also try and use raw_input() as oppose to input() where necessary or cast the output using `variable_name` to get rid of tracback error.